# No option of debug JS remotely on Android simulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am using android 8.1 simulator to debug my React Native (0.62) app with VS code on Win10. After firing up the app with `react-native run-android`, Ctrl+m brings up the dev menu:

[image]

But there is no option of `Debug JS remotely` in the menu. How can I bring up the option of `Debug JS Remotely`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to debug a RN app in Chrome dev tools, unless you are running a production build.
If you want to [use another debugger](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging.html#debugging-using-a-custom-javascript-debugger), you can set it with the `REACT_DEBUGGER` env. variable. Example:

```
REACT_DEBUGGER="node /path/to/launchDebugger.js --port 2345 --type ReactNative"
```

For VSCode there is [this extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native). There is a [section](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native#debugging-react-native-applications) explaining how to debug.